# How do i use the return statement of one method in another private method?

Tags: java, class, methods

This is my Code that I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class VoteRecorder 
{
// Variables and instance variables
 public static String nameCandidatePresident1;
 public static String nameCandidatePresident2;
 public static String nameCandidateVicePresident1;
 public static String nameCandidateVicePresident2;
 public static int votesCandidatePresident1;
 public static int votesCandidatePresident2;
 public static int votesCandidateVicePresident1;
 public static int votesCandidateVicePresident2;
 private int myVoteForPresident;
 private int myVoteForVicePresident;


 public VoteRecorder()
 {
     nameCandidatePresident1 = "null";
     nameCandidatePresident2 = "null";
     nameCandidateVicePresident1 = "null";
     nameCandidateVicePresident2 = "null";
     votesCandidatePresident1 = 0;
     votesCandidatePresident2 = 0;
     votesCandidateVicePresident1 = 0;
     votesCandidateVicePresident2 = 0;
     myVoteForPresident = 0;
     myVoteForVicePresident = 0;     
 }


 public void setCandidatesPresident(String name1, String name2)
 {
     nameCandidatePresident1 = name1;
     nameCandidatePresident2 = name2;

 }

 public void setCandidatesVicePresident(String name1, String name2)
 {
    nameCandidateVicePresident1 = name1;
    nameCandidateVicePresident2 = name2;
 }

 public static void resetVotes()
 {
     votesCandidatePresident1 = 0;
     votesCandidatePresident2 = 0;
     votesCandidateVicePresident1 = 0;
     votesCandidateVicePresident2 = 0;   
 }

 public static String getCurrentVotePresident()
 { 
     return nameCandidatePresident1 + ":" + votesCandidatePresident1 + "\n" +
            nameCandidatePresident2 + ":" + votesCandidatePresident2;
 }

 public static String getCurrentVoteVicePresident()
 {
     return nameCandidateVicePresident1 + ":" + votesCandidateVicePresident1 +  "\n" +
            nameCandidateVicePresident2 + ":" + votesCandidateVicePresident2;
 }


 public void getAndConfirmVotes()
 {

 }


private String getVotes()
{
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("please vote for a President or vice president "     + nameCandidatePresident1 + ", " + nameCandidatePresident2 + ", " + nameCandidateVicePresident1
             + " or " + nameCandidateVicePresident2);
     String presidentVote = keyboard.nextLine();
     if (presidentVote.equalsIgnoreCase(nameCandidatePresident1))    
         return nameCandidatePresident1;

     if(presidentVote.equalsIgnoreCase(nameCandidatePresident2))     
         return nameCandidatePresident1;     

     System.out.println("please vote for a Vice president " + nameCandidateVicePresident1 + " or" + nameCandidateVicePresident2);
     String vicePresidentVote = keyboard.nextLine();

     if(vicePresidentVote.equalsIgnoreCase(nameCandidateVicePresident1))
         return nameCandidateVicePresident1;

     if(vicePresidentVote.equalsIgnoreCase(nameCandidateVicePresident2))
         return nameCandidateVicePresident2;

     else 
         return "not a valid vote";

}


private boolean confirmVotes()
{
   System.out.println("Your vote for President is:");
   System.out.println("your vote for Vice President is:");
   System.out.println("Is this correct? Yes or No?");
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
   if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
        return true;
   else 
       return false;
}

private void recordVote()
{
puscode: If confirmVotes returns true, take the nameCandidate, and ++ to votesCandidate of the   same type
Copy this If statement four times, one for each of the candidates, 2 president and 2 vp.
Else or If confirmvotes returns false, put output saying that  the votes were not confirmed.

}


}
```

Say i had all this code, lets look at the method getVotes() and confrimVotes(), in getVotes() the user picks a candidate and than that candidate is returned. How would i get that return statement to show up else where in other methods? like in confirmVote() i want to  do this

```
 System.out.println("Your vote for President is: (PresidentialCandidate return statement");
```

But how can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but I think your code could be made a lot simpler by harnessing some of the power of object-oriented programming.

You are storing multiple types of information about 4 candidates for different positions as separate variables, and it's making your class very unwieldy.

A (in my opinion) better approach would be to have e.g. a `Candidate` class to store information about a single candidate, and then your classes could look as follows:

```
class Candidate {
    String Name;
    int votes;
}

class VoteRecorder {
     Candidate[] presidents;
     Candidate[] vicePresidents;

     Candidate myVoteForPresident;     //Or even make these both ints.
     Candidate myVoteForVicePresident;
}
```

The classes can be further refined, but this will be a start. Any time you see multiple pieces of information that describe the same entity being repeated multiple times, it's a good indication that you could simplify your life by adding a class to represent them together instead.

**Edit (to answer question specifically):**

If you want to do effectively the following:

> System.out.println("Your vote for President is: (PresidentialCandidate return statement");

You can write something like this:

```
String voteResult = getVotes();
System.out.println("Your vote for President is: " + voteResult);
```

Or in one line:

```
 System.out.println("Your vote for President is: " + getVotes());
```

Each time you run this code though, it will prompt the user for input. If you want to save the result until next time as well, you will have to save it to an attribute, e.g. by having a string in your class, and assigning the value to it first. Then just use that later instead of the local variable `voteResult`.

Comment: i realize there are flaws to this but that is how the assignment tells me to do it. I just need to know what i am asking, i thank you for your help on suggesting another class but even if i set that up i would still be in the same problem.